# How to check String[] array having value "" in an if condition in MVC4?

Tags: c#, arrays, asp.net-mvc-4

May be the questions look simple or may be the solution is also simple.But i have tried lot,But cant make this possible,
I have a string[] **array which has a value=""**.And i want to check this in an if condition

```
if (del.counts==null && del.mrate==null)
{
///
}
```

I *have tried IsNullorEmpty,equal*..etc but nothing gives me the solution
[image: Value iside String[] array]

Comment: `string.IsNullOrEmpty(del.counts[0])`? Note that it is not `del.counts` which has the value `""`. It is the first element inside it: `del.counts[0]`

Comment: @rafalon perfect,Could u please post this below as answer?so that i can accept and close this post

Comment: MindSwipe beat me to it, feel free to mark his/her answer instead :)

Comment: Thanks @Rafalon, I honestly didn't see your comment until i already posted my answer ^^

Comment: @MindSwipe no problem, I know that answers belong to the "Answer" section, but I keep writing comments when I feel like it's too small of an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use array indexing if you know where in the array the element is that you want to check. So like this in your case:

```cs
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(del.counts[0]))
{
    // Code
}
```

If you do not know where the element is you'll want to use Linq's `Any(...)` extension Mehtod.

```cs
if (del.counts.Any(value => string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
{
    // Code
}
```

`Any(...)` will return `true` if any element of the array is `NullOrEmpty` and false if not

So you would use it like so in your application:

```cs
if (del.counts == null && del.mrate == null)
{
    // Your code to handle if 'del.counts' and 'del.mrate' are null
}
// We know 'del.counts' is not null, but one of the elements may be NullOrEmpty
else if (del.counts.Any(value => string.IsNullOrEmpty(value)))
{
    // Your code to handle if one of the counts elements IsNullOrEmpty
}
```

You may want to remove the `else if` and replace it with an `if` statement depending on your context